# Use sql variables in query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some of the following code:

```
Select p.CLIENT_NO,
       s.CLIENT_NAME,
       s.CLIENT_TYPE,
       p.GL_CODE,
       p.BATCH_KEY
  From RU_POST        p,
       RU_ACCT        a,
       Ru_Ru          s
 Where 
   a.INTERNAL_KEY(+) = p.INTERNAL_KEY
   And p.Batch_Key in
   (Select Distinct (p1.BATCH_KEY)
          From RU_POST p1
         Where Abs(p1.AMOUNT) <> 0
           And p1.POST_DATE Between To_Date('01-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') And
               To_Date('01-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
           And p1.INTERNAL_KEY In ('367', '356'))
```

Now I want to have values stated in p1.INTERNAL_KEY to appear in query results, like if I did `SELECT p1.INTERNAL_KEY`.
However, I understand this won't work. So, it would be like '367' for 100 values, '356' for other 100.
Could someone help me how to put this condition value inside my result?

Like that:

```
CLIENT_NO   CLIENT_SHORT    CLIENT_NAME GL_CODE INTERNAL_KEY
399999000   399999  A   4568    367
599999000   599999  B   4879    356
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you want?  My feeling here is that you would need dynamic SQL to get what you want.

Comment: Sure, added in main question

Comment: Looks like this should be tagged Oracle and SQL, not any of the tags actually used.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `DISTINCT` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies too all columns of the select list. Enclosing a column with parentheses won't change anything. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a`. And `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,b,(c)`

Comment: And `in (subquery)` is implicitly distinct anyway, so it should be just `select p1.batch_key`.

Comment: Are there any joins that are not shown in the example? The solution may be to change the `in` construction to a join, but at the moment it's a three way Cartesian product.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, there are no joins, basically it is pretty simple script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing the `in` subquery to a join, like this:

```
select distinct
       p.client_no
     , s.client_name
     , s.client_type
     , p.gl_code
     , p1.internal_key
from   ru_post p
       join ru_post p1 on p1.batch_key = p.batch_key
       left join ru_acct a on a.internal_key = p.internal_key
       cross join ru_ru s
where  abs(p1.amount) <> 0
and    p1.post_date between date '2015-01-01' and date '2015-01-01'
and    p1.internal_key in ('367', '356') );
```

(Edited to match updated question - now left join `ru_post` to `ru_acct`):

Comment: It appeared that I had old-style join in my query)  `a.INTERNAL_KEY(+) = p.INTERNAL_KEY` and now it gives me ORA-25156 because of that

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. That isn't in the query you posted, and changing the `join` to `left join` in my version should not give ORA-25156. What isn't working exactly?

Comment: I edited the original query; you code works good, I just simplified the query because I did't get that it had an old-style join.

Comment: Ok, fixed now, thus your code works great. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, OK. Updated answer - now `left join ru_acct a on a.internal_key = p.internal_key`